Which format and mount points do I require for my Other Location drives to be seen by Plex media server when trying to add libraries?
I have just installed 22.04 LTS.
There are 3 HDDs in the system.
dev/sdc is the OS SSD.
dev/sda is 4Tb GPT Ext4.....there are no files on this drive.
dev/sdb is 2Tb MBR NTFS/exFat/HPFS...ALL media is on it!
All 3 drives were previously in a Win10 HTPC, (if that matters).
I want to run a Plex Media Server in Docker Compose.
Once everything is setup and I go on to my PMS account,
then try to add a library from the 2Tb drive the folders are not found!
Why? How do I get both other location drives to be recognized in plex?
Thanks in advance.
